# ctime() return a string, why we don't need to free() this string' s memory?

Tags: c, string, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

the prototype of the function `ctime` is

```
char *ctime(const time_t *timep);
```

As we can see, it return a string. but, where the sting be contained?

and why we shouldn't free the string's memory

This is sample code will get a lots of error message

```
char *p;
p = ctime(...);
...
free(p);
```

*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f0b365b4e60 ***

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It returns a pointer to a `static` buffer, and must not be `free()`d. From [man ctime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime):

> The four functions asctime(), ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() return a pointer to static data and hence are not thread-safe.

The C99 standard, section *7.23.3.2 The ctime function* states that calling `ctime(timer)` function is equivalent to `asctime(localtime(timer))`, and the `asctime()` implementation (as illustrated in the same document) is equivalent to:

```
char *asctime(const struct tm *timeptr)
{
    static const char wday_name[7][3] = {
        "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
    };

    static const char mon_name[12][3] = {
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };

    static char result[26];
    sprintf(result,
            "%.3s %.3s%3d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d %d\n",
            wday_name[timeptr->tm_wday],
            mon_name[timeptr->tm_mon],
            timeptr->tm_mday, timeptr->tm_hour,
            timeptr->tm_min, timeptr->tm_sec,
            1900 + timeptr->tm_year);

    return result;
}
```

The argument passed to `free()` must be a pointer returned by a call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` only, otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Just adding that if you want a thread-safe version, use ctime_r() instead.

Comment: @Turix, yep it states that on the linked page.

Comment: I really think those arrays are `[][4]` (or, even better, pointer arrays to avoid this bug).

Comment: So, its allocating in global memory. Won't that be filled out when we call the function again and again?

Comment: @Vamshi Yes, it would be best to copy the data from the static memory immediately following the call.

Answer (score 2):

It points to static data and wasn't malloc'd.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer `p` was not dynamically allocated with `malloc` or `calloc`, so you didn't ask for `heap memory` to be `freed`.

Your `p` is just a regular pointer pointing to some memory which was previously allocated (so available for you).

The variable that you give to `ctime()` should be created somewhere else and the creator of that variable is the owner of the resource borrowed to your pointer `p`, so your pointer is just an `observer`, not a `resource owner`, so there's nothing to be freed from your pointer.